# How to redirect from own application another application?

Tags: android

I am creating my own app and at one point I want that user can go to any other application.So what will be the best code for that?

Comment: create an intent with action and then startactivity

Comment: the best code is the one you write yourself.

Comment: Plz take a look [How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in many ways, but one of the common method is intents. You can create **implicit intents** for this purpose.

here is a sample code :

```
//From MainActivity.onCreate()

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
startActivity(intent);`
```

you can find further details about intents [here](http://codetheory.in/android-intents/).

Comment: @MD The questions is not very clear though. But i presume that is what the user want. Just giving a helping hand to a newbee.